# How do I reverse each word in a string, but in the same sentence order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, converters, reverse

I tried doing this

```
while 1:
    line = input('Line: ')
    print(line[::-1])
```

but all that did was reverse the whole sentence, I was wondering if someone could help me with a program that converts 'hello world' to 'olleh dlrow' instead of 'dlrow olleh', and how do I make a loop that stops when the input is nothing, or just a space? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to split the sentence, reverse the words, then reassemble.

The simplest way to split is to do so on whitespace, with `str.split()`; reassembly is then just a case of re-joining the reversed words with a space:

```
' '.join([word[::-1] for word in line.split()])
```

Demo:

```
>>> line = 'hello world'
>>> ' '.join([word[::-1] for word in line.split()])
'olleh dlrow'
```

Comment: Thank You so much! And for the while loop, if there is nothing in the input, does it just go to the next command?

Comment: If `line` is an empty string, splitting returns a list with one empty string as the contents, so this code reverses the empty string, then rejoins that, resulting in an empty string. :-)

Comment: If you want to skip empty lines, just test for them; `if not line: continue`.

Comment: And let's say I want to write all my 'lines' and when I have no more to write, I press enter when asked for another line, and it will print all the reversed text, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Samir: You'd collect all those lines into a list object, then loop over the lines in the list object and apply my answer to each before printing.

Comment: May I ask how that is done? Thank you :)

Comment: You need to do *some* work yourself. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am sure you know it. The outer square brackets can be safely removed for the same functionality (i.e. generator expression instead of the generated list).

Comment: @pepr: Using a list comprehension in `str.join()` is faster than a generator expression, because `str.join()` will turn the generator expression into a list *anyway*; it needs to loop over the sequence twice to calculate the output size first, then build the string. A list comprehension beats out a generator in speed tests here.

Comment: 'line = input('Line: ')
while line != '':
    list1 = []
    line = input('Line: ')
    apend = ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in line.split())
    list1.append(line)
    print(list1)'
I'm pretty sure this is wrong, because it doesn't work, and i don't know how to fix it, any tips?

Comment: @Samir: You want to put your `list1 = []` **outside** your while loop, because otherwise you are replacing it each time there's a new line.

Comment: line = input('Line: ')
list1 = []
while line != '':
    line = input('Line: ')
    list1.append(line)
print(' '.join(word[::-1] for word in line.split()))

I still don't know how to fix it, am I blind, is the correct answer right in front of me.

Comment: Why don't you post a new question with that problem?

Comment: @pepr: See [list comprehension without \[ \], Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9060653)